Bold font with currency prefix in siunitx table
How can the totals in the last column be made bold, i.e the number along with the currency prefix (£).
MWE
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \newcommand{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-all}
    \sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,round-mode=places, round-precision=2,}
    \robustify\textsterling 
    \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{k}[1]{S[table-format = 8.2, table-column-width=3cm, 
table-space-text-pre =\textsterling, table-number-alignment=right, detect-weight=true]} 
            \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{l  k{}}
                 \toprule
                 \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Cost} \\
                 \midrule
                 Item 1 &   \textsterling 916992.   \\ 
                 Item 2 &   \textsterling 1150880.00\\ 
                 Item 3 &   \textsterling 1235392.00\\  \midrule
                 \textbf{Total Cost} &  \B \textsterling4477175.00 \\  \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
           \end{table}
    
 \end{document}



I'm not sure why specifying k with an argument without using it and also why stating a width.
I'd not repeat the £ symbol every time, but just show it in the column header (the less distractions, the better). If you really want the repetition, allocate a column for it, which is much easier to control.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{detect-all}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,round-mode=places, round-precision=2,}
\newcommand{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

%\robustify\textsterling 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

% local assignment
\newcolumntype{k}{S[
  table-format = 7.2,
  detect-weight=true
]} 

\begin{tabular}{@{} l c @{ } k @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Cost}} \\
\midrule
Item 1 & \textsterling &  916992.00 \\ 
Item 2 & \textsterling & 1150880.00 \\ 
Item 3 & \textsterling & 1235392.00 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Total Cost} &  \bfseries \textsterling & \B 4477175.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfil
\begin{tabular}{@{} l k @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Cost (\textsterling)} \\
\midrule
Item 1 &  916992.00 \\ 
Item 2 & 1150880.00 \\ 
Item 3 & 1235392.00 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Total Cost} & \B 4477175.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} l k @{}}
\toprule
Column 1 & {Cost (\textsterling)} \\
\midrule
Item 1 &  916992.00 \\ 
Item 2 & 1150880.00 \\ 
Item 3 & 1235392.00 \\
\midrule
Total Cost & \B 4477175.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Three tables to compare}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Top left “ugly”, top right “bad”, bottom “good”.

A well-designed table should be able to convey all essential information without resorting to bold-facing. For the table at hand, this means not bold-facing the contents of the first and last rows. The fact that horizontal lines separate these rows from the main body of the table should suffice to give them an adequate amount of visual prominence. However, if you simply must use bold-facing for certain cells, just insert an instance of the \B macro which you've defined in your code at that start of the cells in question.
A separate comment: Instead of prefacing each and every cell in the data rows of column 2 with \textsterling, it would be better to place this information in the header cell of column 2.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-all,
             group-separator = {,},
             group-minimum-digits=4,
             round-mode=places, 
             round-precision=2}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[ht]
   \begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format = 7.2] @{}}
      \toprule
      Column 1 & {Cost, in \textsterling} \\
      \midrule
      Item 1 &  916992 \\ 
      Item 2 & 1150880 \\ 
      Item 3 & 1235392 \\  
      \midrule
      Total Cost & 4477175 \\ % why not 3303264?
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}

